# DB2 and SQL-How to return max value in a particular field so that only one record shows up per row; pulling data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, db2, duplicates, max

All,
My data set below pulls WONO, EPLSNM, and SQNO1 from three separate tables.  What I need is a db2 sql query that will return the Employee Name (EPLSNM) per unique WONO with the max SQNO1.

```
WONO    EPLSNM               SQNO1
CA04269 WILLIAMS, BILLY W   12
CA04269 WILLIAMS, BILLY W   12
CA04269 WILLIAMS, BILLY W   12
CA04269 WILLIAMS, BILLY W   12
CA04270 FAIRCLOTH, MARK E   22
CA04270 FAIRCLOTH, MARK E   22
CA04270 FAIRCLOTH, MARK E   22
CA04270 FAIRCLOTH, MARK E   22
CA04270 FAIRCLOTH, MARK E   23
CA04270 FAIRCLOTH, MARK E   23
CA04270 FAIRCLOTH, MARK E   23
CA04270 FAIRCLOTH, MARK E   23
```

I would like to see the following if possible:

```
WONO    EPLSNM               SQNO1
CA04269 WILLIAMS, BILLY W   12
CA04270 FAIRCLOTH, MARK E       23
```

I only need the 2 rows of data versus the 12 I got.

Thank you so much.

Here is my code:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT WOHDR.wono,EMP.eplsnm,max(WOLBR.sqno1) AS SQNO,WOLBR.cgcd,CASE WHEN WOHDR.opndt8 IN (' ') THEN DATE('1900-01-01') WHEN WOHDR.opndt8 IS NULL THEN DATE('1900-01-01') ELSE Date(Cast(SUBSTRING(WOHDR.opndt8,1,4) as char(4)) ||'-'|| Cast(SUBSTRING(WOHDR.opndt8,5,2) as char(2)) ||'-'|| Cast(SUBSTRING(WOHDR.opndt8,7,2) as char(2))) END AS OpenDate,CASE WHEN WOHDR.prmdt8 IN (' ') THEN DATE('1900-01-01') WHEN WOHDR.prmdt8 IS NULL THEN DATE('1900-01-01') ELSE Date(Cast(SUBSTRING(WOHDR.prmdt8,1,4) as char(4)) ||'-'|| Cast(SUBSTRING(WOHDR.prmdt8,5,2) as char(2)) ||'-'|| Cast(SUBSTRING(WOHDR.prmdt8,7,2) as char(2))) END AS PromisedDate,WOHDR.divi AS Division, WOHDR.cunm AS CustName, WOHDR.eqmfmd AS Model,WOHDR.stno AS StoreNo,RPT.ds5 AS StoreName,WOHDR.acti

FROM libd09.wophdrs0 WOHDR 
JOIN libd09.wopsegs0 WOSEG ON (WOHDR.wono = WOSEG.wono)
JOIN libd09.fnlrlvl0 RPT ON (WOHDR.stno = RPT.st4 AND WOHDR.stno = WOSEG.stn1)
LEFT JOIN libd09.cipname0 NME ON (NME.cuno = WOHDR.cuno)
LEFT JOIN libd09.woplabr0 WOLBR ON (WOHDR.wono = WOLBR.wono)
LEFT JOIN libd09.wopempf0 EMP ON (EMP.epidno = WOLBR.epidno AND WOHDR.stno = EMP.stn1)
WHERE WOHDR.opndt8 BETWEEN 20130101 AND YEAR(CURRENT DATE) * 10000 + MONTH(CURRENT DATE) * 100 + DAY(CURRENT DATE) 
AND WOHDR.divi = 'G'
AND NME.cuno NOT LIKE ('I%')
AND RPT.rplvl = ' ' 
AND WOHDR.cunm NOT IN ('ACCRUED VACATION TIME','ACCRUED VACATION','SICK TIME','SICK PAY')
AND WOHDR.acti IN ('O','C')
-- AND DATE(Cast(SUBSTRING(WOLBR.docdt8,1,4) as char(4)) ||'-'|| Cast(SUBSTRING(WOLBR.docdt8,5,2) as char(2)) ||'-'|| Cast(SUBSTRING(WOLBR.docdt8,7,2) as char(2))) = DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(WOHDR.llbjd8)))

GROUP BY
WOHDR.wono,EMP.eplsnm,WOLBR.cgcd,WOHDR.opndt8,WOHDR.divi,WOHDR.cunm, WOHDR.eqmfmd,WOSEG.wosgno,WOHDR.stno,WOHDR.prmdt8,RPT.ds5,WOHDR.acti
```

Comment: always best to show your code & what you have tried.

Comment: Especially as the answers seem to be assuming a simple direction, but your initial question seems to be going somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as an aggregation query:

```
SELECT WONO, EPLSNM, MAX(SQNO1)
FROM whatever w
GROUP BY WONO, EPLSNM;
```

EDIT:

(Based on clarification in comment)

You can use window/analytic functions:

```
select wono, eplsnm, sqn01
from (select w.*, row_number() over (partition by wono order by sqno1 desc) as seqnum
      from whatever w
     ) w
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Gordon. thank you for the response and I do wish it was as easy as grouping and getting the max(sqno1) but after doing that I still get multiple rows for each WONO.                           WONO EPLSNM               SQNO                                         GW25261 CROSS, BRADLEY R 3                             GW25261 DAVIS, DAVID L         2                                   I think this is happening because there are 2 different employees assigned to WONO GW25261, but what I need it to do is just show one line per WONO. In this case Cross should show since he has the higher SQNO (3vs2)

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat difficult to decipher your data, but it seems like you just need a simple group by?

```
SELECT WONO, EPLSNM, MAX(SQNO1)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY WONO, EPLSNM
```

Edit: Due to additional clarification.

```
SELECT WONO, EPLSNM, SQNO1
FROM MYTABLE mt
WHERE SQNO1 = (SELECT MAX(SQNO1) FROM MYTABLE WHERE WONO = mt.WONO)
```